# Vim commandline history and viminfo

Tags: command-line, command-history, viminfo

I can't understand why when I open (Win10) gvim91 and press `:<up>` I don't see my most recent command. I'm sure it used to be this way in previous versions of vim (I updated recently).

What I see are *kind of* recent, but there are obvious gaps where I know there should be commands I've done in the past session.

Also, when I press `q:` and view command history this way, I see a *different* view of my commands. Again, obviously recent but with gaps.

In both I don't see commands I would expect and know I have made.

And then, when I view my viminfo file, after the header "# Command Line History (newest to oldest):", the list is different again from *both* `q:` command history and `:<up>`.

I believe that viminfo is only written when a buffer or window is closed and I've taken this into account.

Can someone explain what's going on?

[Edit]

OK I realise I'll need some proof of this. I've recorded the following actions with vim closed.

1. Open viminfo. You can see the list of the latest commands (which are *not* in fact latest commands but that's the problem!)
2. Open a test file and source a session file to get it sitting pretty under the viminfo file for recording purposes. (My problem doesn't usually involve session files).
3. Hit `:<up>`. As you can see, if you're quick, is that as I hit `<up>` the supposed most recent commands do not match those in the viminfo files.
4. I now enter command history with `q:`. Again, as you can see, the list doesn't match that in viminfo file. Nor, if you care to watch the gif from the beginning, does it match the list when entering `:<up>`.
5. I close the test file. The opened viminfo wants to load the newly written viminfo file; which it does. But look! The 'latest' commands do not list the commands from the test file. In fact, the first one is a command from a session ages ago.

[image]

PS: A pity can't post vid files here: GIFs are difficult to 'parse'.

[Edit]

[image]

[Edit]

More forensics :) For this I renamed (ie removed) the viminfo to start a new one.

1. Open blank vim.
2. Run `:grep 'drawtext' *ffmpeg*`, `:cope`, `:cclo` and `:q!`.
3. Open blank vim.
4. Run `:e ffmpeg …`, `:g/drawtext`, `q:`, `:q` and `:q!`.

The output of the last `q:` was:

```
grep 'drawtext' *ffmpeg*
cope
cclo
q!
e ffmpeg-video-text-overlay.md
g/drawtext
```

5. I open another blank vim and run `:history` then `:q`.

The output from this `:history` command was:

```
:history
      #  cmd history
      1  cclo
      2  cope
      3  grep 'drawtext' *ffmpeg*
      4  e ffmpeg-video-text-overlay.md
      5  g/drawtext
      6  q
      7  q!
>     8  history
```

6. I open viminfo file. The contents of `# Command Line History` section (in its entirety):

```
# Command Line History (newest to oldest):
:q
|2,0,1709726741,,"q"
:g/drawtext
|2,0,1709726741,,"g/drawtext"
:e ffmpeg-video-text-overlay.md
|2,0,1709726741,,"e ffmpeg-video-text-overlay.md"
:grep 'drawtext' *ffmpeg*
|2,0,1709726741,,"grep 'drawtext' *ffmpeg*"
:cope
|2,0,1709726741,,"cope"
:cclo
|2,0,1709726741,,"cclo"
:q!
|2,0,1709726741,,"q!"
:history
|2,0,1709726741,,"history"
```

Comment: The content of `.viminfo` being different from `q:` or `:<Up>` is expected, but without seeing either list it will be hard to reason about the discrepancies you describe. Can we have a minimal reproducible example? How many sessions do you have open at the same time?

Comment: viminfo file is only written once exiting Vim or explicitly using the `:wviminfo` command

Comment: Do you have a discrepency between the list that appear when you hit `q:` and the order of the command that comes with `:<up>`?

Comment: I am aware that viminfo only written when exiting vim. Testing was done with this fact in mind. And, yes, there's a discrepancy in the listing between `q:` and order of commands when hitting `:<up>`. Also a discrepancy between listing of either of the above when first opening vim and the contents of viminfo **# Commands**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. One more question: Do you have multiple sessions of Vim running in parallel (more than one vim process at the same time)?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the name of your `viminfo` file. Do you name it explicitly using the `-i` flag? By default it should be `~/.viminfo` on Linux and `~\_viminfo` on Windows but yours seems to be `viminfo.vim`. I would be glad to compare the content of `~/.viminfo` with the output of the `:history` Vim command.

Comment: Only one vim session running when making these tests.

Yes, I have `set viminfo=!,'5000,s100,h,n~/vimfiles/viminfo.vim` in vimrc

Comment: Thanks for the input but what we would need is the end of the history (not the start) to compare both :-| (sorry I should have been more clear).

Comment: Would also be good that you don't use a session because it include a lot of command in the `viminfo` and I don't have enough view on your history. If you could put the `viminfo` in textual form instead of screenshot would also be helpful (I'm demanding sorry again)

Comment: I suspect that you have some automatic session running since all your timestamp are the same (1709726741 = 2024/03/06 13:05:41). Can you make the same experiment with `vim --clean -i ~/.viminfo`.

Comment: OK so clean vim all good - commands all present and in order ***except*** for `:q!` where I quit the first file I opened (same procedure as above with 'new' viminfo).  Is this a feature? Duplicate `:q!` removed? 

Looks like I'm going to have to start looking at what I have added to vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of the commands that you see in the list triggered by:

- `q:`
- `:hist`

should be the list of commands you executed (the last executed one in the bottom of the list).

The `:`<kbd>up</kbd> should retrieve the last one.

The `:`<kbd>up</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> should retrieve the penultimate.

The `:`<kbd>up</kbd><kbd>up</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> should retrieve the third-to-last.

Remark: `:h`<kbd>up</kbd> do the same but filters the commands that starts with `h`. To get rid of the filtering effect you can use `:`<kbd>Ctrl p</kbd>

### Under the Hood

The `viminfo` file contains the list of commands that have been validated (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) or canceled (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) together with the timestamp corresponding to their last validation or cancellation.

Vim writes the `viminfo` when you quit the Vim session (or when calling `:wviminfo`). When it writes the `viminfo` it actually merges the `viminfo` with the current content of the `viminfo` on disk.

It updates the timestamp of each command used or insert new command in the history with their timestamp.

The `viminfo` list of commands starts with the commands updated by the last session of Vim that exit or that called `:wviminfo`.

Remarks: This implies that the commands in the `viminfo` file are not sorted by timestamp when there were multiple sessions of Vim running in parallel.

#### Viminfo order vs. History order

The commands in Vim are listed according to the timestamp of their execution and not in the order they appear in the `viminfo` file. This explains why the order is different.

#### Viminfo content vs. History content

Although `:wviminfo` merge the content of the `viminfo` on disk it doesn't update the content of the history. This explains why some commands could be missing in the history when you have concurrent sessions of Vim.

#### :rviminfo doesn't update the timestamp

Although `:rviminfo` reads the the content of the `viminfo` and update the history it seems that it doesn't update the command timestamp. The new command will be positioned correctly but command of concurrent session will not be re-positioned after `:rviminfo`.

Comment: In english we say "penultimate" or "second-to-last", then "third-to-last" :)

Comment: Thanks I have used Google translate to get a suggestion but the nothing compare to a human :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I traced problem to Markbar plugin.